# May the Lord reward your work.. Ruth 2:12

Tags: prophecy, ruth

Ruth 2:12 (NASB)

> "May the Lord reward your work, and your wages be full from the Lord,
>   the God of Israel, under whose wings you have come to seek refuge.”

**What reward did Ruth receive for her work?**

Answer (score 3):

2:14 - She was invited to join Boaz and his harvesters in a meal.  (A remarkable and uncommon privilege that few foreigners enjoyed among the Israelites.)

2:16-18 - The harvesters treat Ruth well and deliberately leave Ruth far more grain to gather than a gleaner normally would receive.

2:21-22 - The opportunity to continue gleaning in Boaz' fields protects Ruth from racist prejudice and possible violence.

3:7-15 - Boaz treats Ruth honorably even though she put herself into a VERY vulnerable position by going in to him alone at night.  He sends her home with a huge portion of food for her & Naomi.

4:1-12 - It plays out that Boaz (and not the other relative) is able to fulfill the role of kinsman-redeemer, marrying Ruth and providing her & Naomi with an heir to secure their inheritance.

4:16-17 - Ruth bears a son with Boaz and in doing so not only secures the family inheritance by continuing Naomi's family line, but gains the honor of joining the line that will produce King David -- and the Messiah, Jesus Christ.

These many rewards line up with several of the "Blessings for Obedience" promised in Deuteronomy 28:1-14:

- The fruit of your womb will be blessed (v.4)
- Your basket and your kneading trough will be blessed (v.5)
- You will be blessed when you come in and blessed when you go out (v.6)
- The Lord will send a blessing on... everything you put your hand to. (v.8)

...which is fair evidence that God was the one in control, working His will through Boaz and His other faithful servants.